# Is it possible to use a TensorFlow 1 model in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

For example, some model has been pre-trained with a TensorFlow 1 architecture. Is it possible to load this TensorFlow 1 model in TensorFlow 2 with `tf.keras.models.load_model(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use tensorflow v1 models in tensorflow v2 you would need to import the compatibility module as `tf.compat.v1` and disable tensorflow v2 behavior through `tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()`

You can load a version 1 model checkpoint through:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

As for using the checkpoint in that way, you would need to convert your model using the training code as `SavedModel` which is the correct format for usage in tensorflow v2.